# What papers do I need so I can start working in the UK as fast as possible?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family, working

I recently posted a question regarding the papers I will need to live legally in the UK with my husband, a Polish citizen. I've got pretty good answers that guided me towards the right steps. So I have been reading a lot about the "registration certificate or residence card as the family member of a European Economic Area (EEA) or Swiss national" which I think this is my case. However, in the guide to fill out the application, it is mentioned that it is not mandatory to obtain it but it makes thinks easier. Anyway, I am planning to follow the steps and to obtain such paper to make our lives easier.One of the papers I need to send with my application is at least three payslips which will take three months to gather them. It means that I will be there for three months or more without working.

My question is the following: if in the guidance of the  "registration certificate or residence card as the family member of a European Economic Area (EEA) or Swiss national" is stated that this is an optional paper, does that mean that I can work as long as I can prove I am married to a EEA citizen? Do you have any idea about this subject?

Comment: You didn't mention where are you from.

Comment: @BerislavLopac would it make a difference?

Comment: IIRC some Commonwealth countries have some specific circumstances. But in any case see my answer below.

Comment: Maria: from my reading of the documentation requirements, you should not need three pay slips.  Any evidence of regular employment should suffice. Who told you that you would need three pay slips?

Comment: Phoong, I found this information in the " Application for a registration certificate or residence card as the family member of a European Economic Area (EEA) or Swiss national"
 To be more specific, I found the information about the three pay slips in the point number 12 that states the following:  Sponsor is currently a qualified person  at least the last 3 months before the date of your application, or  the entire period if they have been a qualified person for less than 3 months.

Comment: @MariaCV the current version of that form, for applications after July 2015, found at https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/451898/eea_fm__07_15.pdf, does not include phrase "3 months" or "three months."  (By the way, there's no "n" in my name -- if you include `@phoog` in your responses, I'll get a notification when you post them.  As it is, I didn't notice your response until I came to check on this question after noticing that you posted your third question.)

Answer (score 1):

The whole process is clearly laid out [here](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/overview), with the specified documents listed in [step #3](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/documents-you-must-provide).

In the overview it is stated:

> You don’t need to apply for a residence card as a family member but it can:
>
> - ...
> - show employers you’re allowed to work in the UK

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether she can work before she receives the certificate.

Comment: It does actually -- under "Overview" it states: "You don’t need to apply for a residence card as a family member but it can [...] show employers you’re allowed to work in the UK [...]"

Comment: You might want to summarize this in your answer.  Link-only answers are discouraged because, among other reasons, links can break.

Comment: Hah just did. :D

Comment: Do you know whether employers can or will accept other evidence of eligibility to work, or is the residence card the only document they can consider?

Comment: It depends on the employer. Technically they don't need any papers at all, but most will require something. I guess some might be willing to accept a marriage certificate, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Phong, this is a very good question. Actually this summarizes all what I wanted to ask. I will post it and I hope someone can guide me.